# Opening a text file and adding to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

1) I'm looking to open a text file with values separated by colons like this:

Name : Daniel
Age : 12
Gender : Male
...

How do I open this text file in Python and add everything to a dictionary so that it ends up like this:

```
dictionary={"Name":"Daniel","Age":"12","Gender","male"...}
```

2) I then want the user to be able to search for a key, let's say "Name" and then the program outputs "Daniel". How can I do this?

Comment: Read the docs... [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and 
[Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score -1):

And what is the separator between lines? 
If it is line break, you can do a `file.readlines()`:

```
yourFile = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = yourFile.readlines()
output = {}
for line in lines:
    #BE CAREFUL! [-2] if window line break (\r\n)
    #You can also do l = line.replace('\r', "").replace("\n", "")
    #Which is better, because it is cross-platform and cross-format
    l = line[-1] 
    output[l.split(':')[0]] = l.split(':')[1]
```

Explanation:

- `yourFile.readlines()` reads file, and return it like `["line1\n", "line2\n"]`
- We do a for, loop, we cut the line break character(s) (\n, \r\n or \r, depends of OS!! it should be only \n, but try...
- for each lines:

  - We split string by column: `"Name:Daniel".split(":")` returns `['Name', 'Daniel']`
  - We append it into the dictionary with `dictionnary['key'] = 'value'` syntax

It should work, but be careful: **Spaces between column stay !!** 
To remove it out, you have to use string.replace (`"Name : Daniel".replace(" ", "")` will returns `"Name:Daniel`" ).

And for return the name, once you have dictionary, nothing simpler: `dictionnary["Name"]` outputs `"Daniel"`.

Answer (score -1):

A suggestion:

```
file = open("file.txt","r")
output_dict={}
lines=file.readlines()
file.close()
line=lines[0].replace(" : "," ")
words=line.split(' ')
for i in range(0,len(words)-1,2):
    output_dict[words[i]]=words[i+1]
print(output_dict)
```